# JQuery Rails update attributes not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

One of my fields in my table needs to be editable.  I am attempting to achieve it by using some JQuery, however, the attribute is not being updated in the database, instead it just deletes the attribute completely and becomes null.  However, my server logs show a commit with the attempted attribute update showing up in a hash.

Rails Controller:

```
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render partial: 'update-advise' }
    end
  end

  def update
    @pan.update_advise!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { redirect_to root_path }
      end
  end
```

Pan Model method:

```
  def update_advise!
    update_attributes!(advise: advise)
  end
```

This is the only attribute I would like to be editable.

My form:

```
<div id='update-advise'>
  <div>
    <h2>New Advise Amount</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form_with model: @pan, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :advise %>
      <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And lastly where I'm writing the jquery, update-advise.js.erb

```
$("#condense-table").hide();
$("#update-advise").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'update_advise_field') %>");
```

As mentioned above, the server log shows a commit but doesn't update the database:

> Started PATCH "/pans/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-19 17:07:43 -0400
>   Processing by PansController#update as JS   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"ccB9wsuhaeAfgpPizUOj/NGYntqNIV/C+h5xEZ3tKtyVjnE8kDk569t/t3CVyYErTptdhgys8Qcm93Fp/S/nMQ==",
>   "pan"=>**{"advise"=>"600"}**, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"1"}   Pan
>   Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pans".* FROM "pans" WHERE "pans"."id" =
>   $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
>   app/controllers/pans_controller.rb:45    (0.2ms)  BEGIN   ↳
>   app/models/pan.rb:5   Battery Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "batteries".*
>   FROM "batteries" WHERE "batteries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳ app/models/pan.rb:5    (0.2ms)  COMMIT   ↳
>   app/models/pan.rb:5    (0.2ms)  BEGIN   ↳
>   app/controllers/pans_controller.rb:15    (0.3ms)  COMMIT   ↳
>   app/controllers/pans_controller.rb:15 Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/ Completed 200 OK in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)

Secondly, is there a way to make the field editable directly in the table without any gems?

Comment: in your controller you do `@pan.update_advise!` which calls `update_advise!` on your model instance, which executes `update_attributes!(advise: advise)`. Where is your `advice` variable in `update_advise!` is coming from ?, I think it's taking the value the record already has in the database, that's why it is `nil`. You need tell your model instance to update the params that you're getting in your controller. For that, you have to do something like `def pan_params; params.require(:pan).permit(:advise);end` and then `@pan.update_attributes(pan_params)` in your controller.

Comment: That was it, so simple, thanks!